# Why does my JMeter While Controller Loop Infinitely?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to set up a JMeter run that does this:

1. Make Rest API request
2. Use a JSON Extractor to check the response for a given array of values.

   - I define success as all of the "Items[*].Success" nodes equaling "true"
3. If the response is successful, break out of the loop (**continue to step #5**)
4. If the response is a failure, **go back to step #1**
5. ... the rest of my test steps

Here's what I've set up to do this:

1. Use a BeanShell Assertion to initialize a loop variable:

   - `${__setProperty(is_any_calc_pending,true)};`
2. While Controller with a condition set to

   - `${__BeanShell(props.get("is_any_calc_pending")}`
   - **My problem is here, the loop never stops**
3. Make Rest API call (This works as expected)
4. JSON Extractor (This also works as expected)

   - Names of created variables = api_successes
   - JSON Path expressions = $.Items[*].Success
   - Match No. = -1
   - Compute concatenation = checked
   - Default Values = unset_api_successes
5. JSR223 PostProcessor set to Javascript to update the value of the loop variable.

Here's my code for step #5.  It simply checks whether or not there's a "false" in the `api_successes_ALL` variable that the JSON Extractor creates.

```
var api_successes_ALL = vars.get('api_successes_ALL')
var all_successful = api_successes_ALL.indexOf('false') < 0
props.put('is_any_calc_pending',!all_successful)
```

Most of this works as I expect; I can check this using the Debug Sampler.  The problem I'm having is that the loop never stops.  The condition never causes the loop to break.

In the log, I see this line:

```
DEBUG o.a.j.c.WhileController: Condition value: 'false'
```

The documentation says that the While Controller will continue until the condition is false.  From what I see in the log, the condition is always false.  I also don't understand why the While Controller never sees that the value of my `is_any_calc_pending` changes.  I can see in the Debug Sampler that the value changes.

Is the variable being re-initialized somehow?  I'm wondering if my variable or property is going out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.  Here's what I did:

- Simple Controller (I'm not sure if this is necessary)

  - Make Rest API call to initiate process
  - While Controller, see condition code below

    - Make Rest API call to check status
    - JSON Extractor with the same property values I listed in my question

I didn't expect it, but the While Controller has access to the variables generated in the JSON Extractor.  I think the Simple Controller may have caused this.

While Controller condition.  I left the log.warn() call in there to show how I debugged the condition.

```
${__javaScript(
    log.warn( vars.get("api_successes_ALL") );

    !!vars.get("api_successes_ALL") ?
    (vars.get("api_successes_ALL").indexOf("false") >= 0) :
    "true";
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

The JSON PostProcessor has to be a child of the Request, not of the While Loop.

Lost a few hours on this.

- WhileLoop

  - HTTP Request

    - JSON extractor
  - Delay